# Qual a melhor maneira de se representar uma tabela de login com dois tipos de autenticações Facebook e Convencional?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, facebook

Eu tenho um app Android e tenho uma activity de login convencional.  Atualmente eu quero adicionar login com redes sociais. Qual a melhor forma de armazenar este tipo de logins distintos em tabelas.
Eu crio uma tabela única ou faço a divisão delas.

Comment: Obrigado não tinha o conhecimento desse tipo de login era chamado de OAuth. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

quando precisei fazer esse tipo de login utilizei uma tabela bem simples para registrar as informações do usuário.

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario
(
    Id INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    PessoaId INTEGER NULL
    LoginEmail VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Senha VARCHAR(30) NULL  
)
```

Note que existem informações que não são obrigatórias (*NULL*), como a senha e o vinculo com a tabela Pessoa, onde registro nome, sexo e outras informações relevantes.

A maior dificuldade que tive era a de entender o fluxo das informações quando se utiliza esse tipo de login (*OAuth*). Nas minhas pesquisas encontrei uns fluxos que me ajudaram muito e gostaria de compartilhar:

**Facebook**

[image: Fluxo do Facebook]

**Google | Microsoft | Linkedin**

[image: Fluxo do Google, MS e Linkedin]

Abaixo também seguem os links para obter os privilégios de segurança com as redes:

**Facebook**
[Clique aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

**Google**
[Clique aqui](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

**Microsoft**
[Clique aqui](https://account.live.com/developers/applications/create?tou=1)

**Linkedin**
[Clique aqui](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp=)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Neste exemplo quando o usuário logar da forma convencional o pessoaid ficaria nulo e senha preenchidos. Caso logar  com o facebook pessoaid seria associado com os dados da tabela pessoa que seria preenchido com as informações obtidas do Facebook e o campo senha ficaria nulo?

Comment: Caso você tenha acesso as informações você pode preencher a tabela Pessoa. No meu caso eu não precisava disso, então só preenchia a tabela Pessoa caso o cadastro do usuário fosse realizado direto no meu sistema.

Answer (score 2):

rapaz, eu uso em uma única tabela. Não sei se é a forma mais correta, mas como trata-se de Login, então uma tabela é o suficiente!
Se você analisar, haverá (teoricamente) apenas um usuário, para diversas contas, então haverá somente uma linha na tabela pro Facebook, Twitter, etc...

Espero ter ajudado!
=)

Comment: É que quando o usuário for convencional o campo senha será obrigatório. Já quando o usuário se logar pelas redes sociais essa informação não tenho ai irei gravar o campo senha nulo. Essa abordagem é um pouco estranha pois isso fiquei com dúvidas.

Comment: @RogerioEsteves, tente usar a constraint `CHECK`.

Comment: Vi este artigo bem interessante http://www.sitepoint.com/social-network-authentication-merging-accounts/